# Trouble using the Formatting

Tags: support, markdown

I can't make multiline blocks, for example a list comes out:

- Num1
- Num2
- Num3

If I try these in a block:

> Num1
> Num2
> Num3

Or with line in between...

> n1
>
> n2
>
> n3

This is definitely not what I want, take a look at this in edit to see what I had compared to what came out. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works for me:

> Num1
>   Num2
>   Num3

The trick is to add two spaces at the end of each line to have a `<br/ >` be inserted.

You can find that and other markdown tricks in the [advanced help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#linebreaks)

Comment: Thanks! So that's the problem I've been having.